# Access denied to write boot record under Windows XP on Award BIOS

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning, bios, partition-recovery

I've recently deleted a NTFS partition by mistake.
I haven't created a new partition in its space (it's unallocated right now).

I tried recovering it using Active@ Partition Recovery software under Windows XP, the program recognised the partition immediately during scan, so I chose to recover it. However, I got "error writing drive" with "access is denied" cause. The program is being run as an Administrator user.

After a bit of googling I figured out it might just be the BIOS' "Boot virus protection", so I started looking for the setting in CMOS setup, but couldn't find any. The motherboard is a Gigabyte M61SME-S2, with an Award BIOS; I searched the manual and there's no reference to boot sector protection whatsoever. I tried flashing the latest BIOS version (version 6 is installed, version 9 is current stable version) with no success (using QFlash my USB drive isn't recognised, and the windows utility exits with no error or success messages, but BIOS is not updated).

I need to recover files in that partition very badly. Is there anything I can do to stop the  "access is denied" error, or any other way to recover the partition? Just in case it's useful, I know the start and end sectors, as well as the number of sectors in the partition, of course. Would it be possible to use GParted or a similar tool to re-create the partition with its original (and existing) content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BIOS virus protection was only useful when the OS would have written through the BIOS functions. 32-bit OSs avoid calling the legacy 16-bit BIOS functions except during boot, so BIOSes have stopped boot virus protection. Newer versions of Windows do block MBR write access to active disks on their own.

A deleted partition can be recovered by creating a new partition in its place. My tool of preference is using a Linux live CD (or USB stick) and run `cfdisk` to recreate the partition. If you want to check (and maybe back up) the data safely from under Linux, then use `mount -o ro /dev/sdXX /mnt` first, which prevents writing to that partition.

Comment: I can't upvote you twice, so just let me upvote you a couple of times... I actually had a better time using `fdisk` instead of `cfdisk`, since I couldn't find a way to enter partition size in sectors in the latter. After mounting as read-only, I backed data up and moved on.

Comment: cfdisk has a [ Unit ] option in the menu at the bottom where you can change between MB, sectors, and (if you really want :-)) cylinders.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using partition software from recovery cd? For example http://lifehacker.com/5984707/five-best-system-rescue-discs
I personally prefer *Hirens bootCD* Recover tools section.